# Migrate Tamper Monkey Script to standalone extensions

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to migrate some tamper monkey script into a standalone chrome extension; however, I am running into a few errors with some functions.

```js
const InputEvents = {};
    function pressKey(key) {
        const wordsInput = document.getElementById("wordsInput");
        const KeyboardEvent = Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_INPUT_OPTIONS, { target: wordsInput, data: key });
        const InputEvent = Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_KEY_OPTIONS, { target: wordsInput, key: key });

        wordsInput.value += key;
        InputEvents.beforeinput(InputEvent);
        InputEvents.input(InputEvent);
        InputEvents.keyup(KeyboardEvent);
    }

function hook(element) {
        element.addEventListener = new Proxy(element.addEventListener, {
            apply(target, _this, args) {
                const [type, listener, ...options] = args;
                if (_this.id === "wordsInput") {
                    InputEvents[type] = listener;
                }
                return target.apply(_this, args);
            }
        })
    }
    hook(HTMLInputElement.prototype);
```

I say this because this code, from a different author, works in TamperMonkey userscript, but when I put the same script into my `script.js` file or in a browser's console, it throws an error saying `.beforeinput() or .input() or .keyup() is not a function`. I tried messing around with Google's bard which suggested some changes with polyfills, which I am unsure of. I not as well versed in Javascript and chrome extensions as I'm new to this area. Any help is much appreciated.